# Powershell Script Not Pulling Event from Event Log

Tags: windows, powershell

Breaking my brian here trying to figure out why this won't pull events from the event log?

I am seeing the event in the event log with the message "The backup operation has completed."

The Event ID is: **14** located under Log Name: **Microsoft-Windows-Backup/Operational**

```
$PastHours = 24

$StartAt = (Get-Date).AddHours(-$PastHours)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$FilterHashTable = @{
    logname   = "Microsoft-Windows-Backup/Operational"
    id        = 14
    StartTime = $StartAt
}

$actions = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashTable | 
    Where-Object {($_.Message -like "*operation*")})

if ($actions){
    ForEach($action in $actions){
        $Result = "OK: Windows Backup Completed Successfully"
        Write-Host $Result
        Exit 0
    }
}
elseif ($action.count -eq "0") {
    $Result = "CRITICAL: Windows Backup has not run in past $PastHours hours "
    Write-Host $Result
    Exit 2
}
else {
    $Result = "CRITICAL: Windows Backup has not run in past $PastHours hours "
    Write-Host $Result
    Exit 2
}
```

I run the script and confirm that every time that $action.count is 0.. The event is present and was run last at 8/8/2018 2:12 PM

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you list `$actions` and see if anything is there? If not, remove `Where-Object` and verify if that helps. At least you'll know what to troubleshoot.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `$actions.count` (plural)

Comment: I removed the Where-Object but still did not find the task. $actions is null - I think when I try and print it.

Comment: It works for me (don't have Windows Backup so I had to use another log) so I don't think I'll be able to help more. Just to confirm - are you running the script on the same machine you checked the logs?

Comment: yes, are you using the same script I posted and it worked?

Comment: Correct. Works like a charm (only change was another log and another id)

Comment: I tested this with another log and id, and it worked fine - Have you tried the logname `Microsoft-Windows-Backup` as opposed to `Microsoft-Windows-Backup/Operational`. Running `Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_.logname -like "*Microsoft-Windows-Backup*" } | fl *` returns `LogName : Microsoft-Windows-Backup; LogType : Operational`. Compare this with other logs which seem to include the `/Operational` in the `LogName`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jacob, you're right.

It's working now using:

```
Param(
    [string]$PastHours
)

$StartAt = (Get-Date).AddHours(-$PastHours)
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$FilterHashTable = @{
    logname   = "Microsoft-Windows-Backup"
    id        = 4
    StartTime = $StartAt
}

$actions = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashTable | 
    Where-Object {($_.Message -like "*successfully*")})

if ($actions){
    ForEach($action in $actions){
        $Result = "OK: Windows Backup Completed Successfully at {1} " -F $Task,$action.TimeCreated
        Write-Host $Result
        Exit 0
    }
}
elseif ($action.count -eq "0") {
    $Result = "CRITICAL: Windows Backup has not run in past $PastHours hours"
    Write-Host $Result
    Exit 2
}
else {
    $Result = "CRITICAL: Windows Backup has not run in past $PastHours hours"
    Write-Host $Result
    Exit 2
}
```